# Effective Way of Increasing/Decreasing Font Size of All Elements on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In order to improve UX, I'm planning to have a font size increase/decrease/reset tool on all the pages of my website (A-, A, A+)

The problem I'm facing is that the font size used by different elements on the page is **not uniform**. Some are 14px, some are 18px, some are 12px and some are 15px.

As such, using the `body` tag for manipulating the font size will not get the desired result.

Is there a solution which will go through each element (get its present size) and increase its font size by 1 if `A+` was clicked or decrease the size by 1 if `A-` was clicked and reset back to the originals if `A` was clicked?

PS: I'm open to jQuery solutions too.

Comment: If I couldn't be bothered changing the font sizes from absolute values to something that is "relative", I would do something in javascript or jquery

Comment: That's why `em` and `rem` units were invented instead of `px`. `rem` refer to the root font size, which then makes increasing and decreasing the whole document's font size super easy using `body{ font-size : 120% };`

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But making the changes at this stage is not a viable option. Hence, I was hoping there would be a not-so-tiresome way of doing it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's why `em` and `rem` units were invented instead of `px`. `rem` refer to the root font size, which then makes increasing and decreasing the whole document's font size super easy using `body{ font-size : 120% };`

But, since you can't use `rem`, here's a dirty solution using jQuery :

```js
var $affectedElements = $("p"); // Can be extended, ex. $("div, p, span.someClass")

// Storing the original size in a data attribute so size can be reset
$affectedElements.each( function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.data("orig-size", $this.css("font-size") );
});

$("#btn-increase").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(1);
})

$("#btn-decrease").click(function(){
  changeFontSize(-1);
})

$("#btn-orig").click(function(){
  $affectedElements.each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , $this.data("orig-size") );
   });
})

function changeFontSize(direction){
    $affectedElements.each( function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css( "font-size" , parseInt($this.css("font-size"))+direction );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p style="font-size : 30px">This text is initially 30px</p>
  <div>
    <p style="font-size : 20px">This text is initially 20px</p>
    <p style="font-size : 10px">This text is initially 10px</p>
    
  </div>  
</div>

<button id="btn-decrease">A-</button>
<button id="btn-orig">A</button>
<button id="btn-increase">A+</button>
```

Comment: Is it a correct assumption of design to just apply this to `p` and `div`? It may be worth pointing out that this solution if copied in exactly may not catch all text on the page (if specific font size style has been applied to `a` or `label`, for instance) and that some experimentation on the Jquery selector is probably required to ensure all text is caught.

Comment: It's because in my simple example, I only put a few `<p>`. Of course, for real use, the selector can be extended to `<span>`, `<strong>` or whatever. Or even `$("*")` if we're being lazy, but I don't like it as it will also select `<script>`, `<head>` and everything else and will be slower. This code is just a kick start.

Comment: Fair enough - I'm just aware of how often answers are taken literally and misunderstood! IMO it wouldn't hurt to add a caveat to the end stating that for real world applications you'd need to list all element types that contain text and that the above was just a sample, but it's probably fine as is. Your answer, your choice!

Comment: Just did so :) I have updated my code, taking your comment into consideration.

Comment: I was struggling with retaining the original font sizes but your idea is quite brilliant. Wonder why I didn't think of storing that as a `data` attribute

Comment: I've turned this in to a small Class with jQuery support: https://gitlab.com/snippets/106398

Comment: @JeremyThille - Any idea how to apply these sizes after rendering HTML by ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Your best and cleanest bet is using `rem` mixed with jQuery.

The difference between my answer and the one above/what you are asking for, is that instead of increasing/decreasing **all** of the font-sizes by 1, this will only change the root font-size, which will cascade down and make all the other fonts **scale** accordingly.

```js
$('#_biggify').on('click', function() {
  var fontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize)+1;
  
  $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize+'px')
})

$('#_smallify').on('click', function() {
  var fontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  var newFontSize = parseInt(fontSize)-1;
  
  $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize+'px')
})

$('#_reset').on('click', function() {
  $('html').css('font-size', '32px')
})
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.smaller {
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Here is a regular piece of text in your document
</div>

<div class="smaller">
Here is text that should be smaller than the rest
</div>

<button id="_biggify">
Make Bigger
</button>

<button id="_smallify">
Make Smaller
</button>

<button id="_reset">
Make Default
</button>
```

> Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Hybridx24/L3yzuvjr/

Comment: OP would like to be able to increment/decrement 1 by 1, not just "make bigger" and "make smaller".

Comment: Please include the main content in the answer.... this is basically a link-only answer.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for the advice